# Using my UK Multi Visit visa

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens

I applied for a UK visa with the reason of "to renew my Philippine passport there in London as there is no longer a Philippine embassy here in Dublin."

Then they issued me a multiple entry visit visa valid until October 2013.

Can I use it to tour the UK in the summer or is it just to be used solely for renewing my passport?

I don't want to be questioned on the immigration there so just wanted to make sure.

Comment: What visa did they issue?

Comment: I think he meant tourist visa from "visit visa".

Comment: Yes, its a general visit visa (multiple entry). Sorry, bit of a stupid question but just need clarity regarding it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

[The main concern](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/policyandlaw/guidance/ecg/vat/vat1/#header5) of the UK Border Agency seems to be to ensure that your visa is only used for visiting, but not for taking up *de facto* residence in the country.

Unless there is a note on the visa that says something along the lines of "may only be used to renew passport", or [otherwise restricts your entry to a specific purpose (see #6)](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/general-info/visa-holders/), you can enter the UK multiple times as a tourist. Both touring the UK and renewing your passport seem to me valid reasons of spending time in the UK that would not be considered akin to taking up residence.